# Advanced Custom Fields on WPML translations not saving

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wpml

On a page/post I can copy the [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com) with content to the translated page but when I edit the translated page it always gets overwritten by the Advanced Custom Fields content from the default language page.

**Trying to achieve:**

I need to copy content with Custom Fields from a default language post to a translated language post, and then edit each language's content independently.

On every other project it just works fine that way…

---

**I've already tried:**

1. [Solving some database errors](https://wpml.org/forums/topic/post-need-update-and-custom-field-dont-save-value/page/2/) - **no success**
2. [Changing the execution order for WPML and ACF](http://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/text-area-fields-are-not-saving-on-update/) - **no success**
3. Deleting WPML completely and deactivating ACF and all other plugins.
   then install WPML first and activate ACF again - **no success.**
4. Tried every possible combination of settings in both plugins available -
   **no success**
5. After setting “translate” for “field groups” and “do nothing” for “fields” at WPML options. I can now create independent custom fields for the translation with independent field_names. Saving here works, but I can't copy content from the default page to translated page. So this is a **partial success**

---

**Next Steps**

- Downgrade ACF to an earlier version.
- Same as step three from above but instead of reinstalling WPML, i reinstall ACF and activate it first of all.

---

**versions:**

- wpml: 3.1.7.2
- acf: 5.0.9
- wordpress: 4.0

---

I've also posted this issue in the [acf support forum](http://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/acf-not-playing-nice-with-wpml/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anybody also has this issue, I was able to solve it after talking to a developer at ACF.

Here is how: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/multilingual-custom-fields/